# Obtener datos de funcion Async

Tags: javascript, nodejs, orm, async-await

estoy haciendo una consulta a la bd para extraer una fila y ponerla segun el tipo de peticion que se realice, entonces tengo esta función en la parte del await esta un Listmensaje que me trae la consulta, el problema es que cuando trato de leer el mensaje me dice funcionPromise pero apesar de que si imprime en consola no se ve en el correo >(

```
async function generateMensaje(){
    const mensajes = await ListMensaje(serviceLocator);
    console.log("mensajes[0].Contenido)=====> " , mensajes[0].Contenido);
    var mensaje = mensajes[0].Contenido;
    return  mensaje;
}

el LisMensaje me trae
siempre llega primero---->  Promise {
  [
    {
      IdMensaje: 1,
      TipoMensaje: 'sms',
      TipoInteresado: 'Cliente',
      Contenido: 'llego?',
      ImagenTemplate: undefined
    },
    {
      IdMensaje: 2,
      TipoMensaje: 'sms',
      TipoInteresado: 'Cliente Industrial',
      Contenido: '2',
      ImagenTemplate: undefined
    },
    {
      IdMensaje: 3,
      TipoMensaje: 'sms',
      TipoInteresado: 'Ejecutivo',
      Contenido: '3',
      ImagenTemplate: undefined
    },
    {
      IdMensaje: 4,
      TipoMensaje: 'sms',
      TipoInteresado: 'Interno',
      Contenido: '5',
      ImagenTemplate: undefined
    },
    {
      IdMensaje: 5,
      TipoMensaje: 'correoElectronico',
      TipoInteresado: 'Cliente',
      Contenido: 'Porfa funciona',
      ImagenTemplate: undefined
    },
    {
      IdMensaje: 6,
      TipoMensaje: 'correoElectronico',
      TipoInteresado: 'Cliente Industrial',
      Contenido: 'llego?',
      ImagenTemplate: undefined
    },
    {
      IdMensaje: 7,
      TipoMensaje: 'correoElectronico',
      TipoInteresado: 'Ejecutivo',
      Contenido: 'holaa',
      ImagenTemplate: undefined
    },
    {
      IdMensaje: 8,
      TipoMensaje: 'correoElectronico',
      TipoInteresado: 'Interno',
      Contenido: 'llego?',
      ImagenTemplate: undefined
    }
  ]
}
```

es una consulta con Orm a la Bd.

Necesito tomar el *contenido* de esa tabla para ponerlo en una funcion que envia correos, seria un complemento al correo

```
function sendEmail(subject, text, attachments, addressee, type) {
    var mailOptions;
    switch (type){
        case "Emisora":
            mailOptions = {
                from: environment.SMTP.USER,
                to: addressee,
                subject: subject,
                text: text,
                html:
                `<p style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;margin:0;">
                    Buenas Tardes,
                </p>
                <p/>
                <p style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;margin:0;">
                    En la siguiente ruta se puede consultar las afectaciones de servicio a los clientes y el programa semanal de consignaciones aprobadas para la siguiente Semana.
                </p>
                <p/>
                <a href="https://ntesAfectados" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" data-auth="NotApplicable" data-linkindex="0" style="color: rgb(133, 181, 255) !important;" data-ogsc="" id="LPlnk590768">https://consignaciones-frontend-dev-app.azurewebsites.net/clientesAfectados</a>` ,
                attachments: attachments,
            };
            break;
        case "Interesado":
        let mensaje =  generateMensaje;
        **console.log("siempre llega primero----> ", mensaje);**
            mailOptions = {
                from: environment.SMTP.USER,
                to: addressee,
                subject: subject,
                text: text,
                html: 
                `<p style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;margin:0;">
                    Buenas Tardes,
                </p>
                <p/>
                <p style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;margin:0;">
                    En la siguiente ruta se puede consultar las afectaciones de servicio a los clientes y el programa semanal de consignaciones aprobadas para la siguiente Semana.
                </p>
                <p/>
                <a href="Afectados" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" data-auth="NotApplicable" data-linkindex="0" style="color: rgb(133, 181, 255) !important;" data-ogsc="" id="LPlnk590768">https://consignaciones-dev-app.azurewebsites.net/client</a>`+
                ` <h1>Victor ${mensaje} </h1> `
                ,
                attachments: attachments
            };
            break;
```

MensajeControloller

```
 async sendEmail(request, h){
        emailService.generateMensaje();        
        return h.response().code(200);
      },
```

ListMensaje

```
'use strict';

module.exports = ({ mensajeRepository }) => {
  return mensajeRepository.find();
};
```

entonces necesito pasar el contenido de Contenido en el html atravez de ${mensaje}, muchas gracias!

ME serviria poder capturar la const mensajes que esta dentro de generatemensaje y usarla fuera de esa funcion, no he podido, agradezco mucho sus ayudas :)

Comment: Puedes mostrar la implementación de la función `ListMensaje` ?

Comment: puedes editar la respuesta y agregar el código

Comment: hola, si ya esta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código que compartes `generateMensaje` es una función asíncrona, el problema es que cuando llamas la función `sendEmail` estás asignando la referencia de la función a la variable `mensaje` en vez del resultado del llamado de esa función:

```
case "Interesado":
  // este es el problema, debes llamar la función, no asignarla:
  let mensaje =  generateMensaje;
  ...
```

Para que ese llamado te pueda funcionar también debes convertir `sendEmail` en una función asíncrona para que puedas usar `generateMensaje`:

```
// agregar async a la definición de la función:
async function sendEmail() {
  ...
  case "Interesado":
    // corregir la asignación:
    let mensaje = await generateMensaje();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hola Mauro, funciono perfectamente lo de volver sendEmail un async, pero quisiera saber lo primero que me dices cuando dices que debo llamar la función y no asignarla te refieres a generateMensaje();? por que lo hice de esa forma y me devuelve un [objet promise]

Comment: @victor recuerda agregar `await`, es decir `let mensaje = await generateMensaje();`

Comment: dale muchas gracias, pense que decias una forma de hacerlo sin volver el sendEmail un async, pero igual funciono, muchas gracias.

Comment: @victor si, lo que pasa es que cuando usas promesas siempre estarás obligado a escribir el código de forma asíncrona, es decir, ya sea usando `async/await` como lo hicimos en este caso o encadenando el código con el método `.then` de la promesa (`generateMensaje().then(function(mensaje) { ... })`) sino que así sería muy engorroso de trabajarlo, es más facil con `async/await`. Te recomiendo este [artículo](https://jonmircha.com/javascript-asincrono) que habla de la asincronía en javascript.

Comment: vale, muchas gracias!